# Wordpress plugin, can't echo the array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to remove all the css files and out put their full path, this is what I'm trying:

```
$cssArray = array();

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'removeStyles', 100 );

function removeStyles() {
    global $wp_styles;

    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ){
        wp_dequeue_style($handle);
        $src = $wp_styles->registered[$handle]->src;
        array_push($cssArray, $src);
    }
}  

add_action('wp_head','hook_css');

function hook_css() {

    $output = "<tag1>";

    foreach ($cssArray as $csses => $css) {
        $output .= $css;
    }

    $output .= "</tag1>";

}
```

The result is just `<tag1></tag1>`.

I even tried to `print_r` the `$cssArray` array, but looks empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you make `$cssArray` global (and declare it that way in each function)?

Comment: Works like a charm!!!!! Tks a lot (post is as an answer so I can approve it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I think the `$cssArray` you've declared isn't available to your functions.  Try making it global.

Answer (score 0):

I think foreach should be like this.

```
 foreach ($cssArray as $csses) {
        $output .=  $csses => $css;
    }
```